# Pass ImageButton Value

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm brand new to android and trying to create an activity that has a fragment inside it. The idea is the fragment has 3 ImageButtons. The ImageButton you click will pass it's image to the activity and then show it in another fragment created after the onClick (full screen ImageView) within the main activity. The problem is I can't figure out how to pass the information. I've read over multiple questions already asked similar to this one, and went over android developers website but the more I read the more confusing it becomes. I'm also running into the problem of findViewById saying it cannot resolve the method. I have no idea why it is telling me this and have tried many things to fix it, nothing is working. Here is my code and any suggestions would be appreciated.

Main Activity:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainActivityFragment.CanPassData{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void passData(int value){
        MainActivityFragment fragment = new MainActivityFragment();
        fragment.setData(5);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment, fragment).commit();
        //***Taken From Android Developer, I believe this is how you create a new fragment when you pass the data to the main activity****
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.getData();
        } else {
            MainActivityFragment newFragment = new MainActivityFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            //******No idea what this is calling, pictureChosen and picture are default values taken from the website*******
            args.putInt(MainActivityFragment.pictureChosen, picture);
            newFragment.setArguments(args);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
        //*****************************************************************************************
    }
    public void processData(){
        MainActivityFragment fragment = (MainActivityFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
        int value = fragment.getData();
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private int data;
    private CanPassData parent;

    public interface CanPassData{
        public void passData(int value);
    }

    public MainActivityFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //***findViewById is saying it cannot resolve below
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        ImageButton button3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        //******************************************************************************************
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

    public void onAttach(MainActivity activity){
        parent = (CanPassData) activity;
    }

    public void setData(int value){
        data = value;
    }
    //***onClick also has all findViewByID as cannot resolve method, and i'm not exactly sure what to do within each case, the stuff I have in there was also taken from android developer.
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.imageButton:
                ImageView box = (ImageView)findViewByID(R.id.imageButton);
                Drawable name = box.getBackground().getCurrent();
                Intent intent = new Intent (this, newFragment.class);
                intent.putExtra("com.example.coding.assignment2", name);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton2:
                box = (ImageView)findViewByID(R.id.imageButton2);
                name = box.getBackground().getCurrent();
                intent = new Intent (this, newFragment.class);
                intent.putExtra("com.example.coding.assignment2", name);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton3:
                box = (ImageView)findViewByID(R.id.imageButton3);
                name = box.getBackground().getCurrent();
                intent = new Intent (this, newFragment.class);
                intent.putExtra("com.example.coding.assignment2", name);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void pushData(){
        parent.passData(data);
    }

    public int getData(){
        return data;
    }
}
```

A lot of the methods such as getData and pushData I'm not exactly sure how to use to get the info to the main activity, it was information given to me during class. I am wondering if there is a way to just pass the drawable itself if it is clicked, then assign that drawable to a ImageView in the new fragment that displays it covering the entire fragment. I've been told I need to make a 2nd fragment xml, but the java file itself should be created via the main activity. Is this correct?

Comment: lol. It can be confusing as there are multiple ways of doing this so what to do? Since your intending to go from fragment -> activity -> fragment you can just create a new class file named (eg) Globals where you define a static drawable or whatever. The OnClick event puts the image into the static global drawable and bam! you can use it anywhere without having to write lines of code everywhere. As its static you'll want to make sure of memory leaks and usage but its reusable though so reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot resolve the `findViewById` because you have to inflate a `View` in order to use Fragments `findViewById`, like this:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, parent, false);
ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
ImageButton button3 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);

//call your button.setOnClickListener
return v;
```

There is no need to call `setContentView()`

In the `onClick(View v)` you also need to call `v.findViewById()`

Also you decleare your variables in a case, you should declare them before any of the case if you want to use them that way. It should look something like this:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    ImageView box=null;
    Drawable name = null;
    Intent intent = null;
    switch(v.getId()){
       case R.id.imageButton:
            box = (ImageView) v.findViewByID(R.id.imageButton);
            name = box.getBackground().getCurrent();
            intent = new Intent (this, newFragment.class);
            intent.putExtra("com.example.coding.assignment2", name);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
```

And so on